# ¿Cómo proceder cuando el problema era un error muy leve en el código?

Tags: discusión, moderación

Me encontré con el caso de que había una pregunta (Link solo moderadores porque ya fue borrada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7645/) que se resolvió en los comentarios porque los datos de entrada que usaba estaban mal.  El problema no era el código y solo fue una ayuda a encontrarlo.

Ya que la pregunta no merecía agregar una respuesta y dificilmente sería útil para otros usuarios en el futuro, sugerí que borrara el post simplemente y así lo hizo.

¿Es así como deberíamos manejar estos casos, con eliminación?

Si se quedaba abierta seguramente iba a ser cerrada o votada en contra.

Comment: Me recordaste a esta pregunta que hice hace tiempo en meta: [Agregar motivo de cierre: El problema no puede ser reproducido o error tipográfico](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/473/227)

Comment: Qué lástima que la borraron.

Answer (score 3):

La premisa es que las preguntas deben evaluarse considerando como mínimo

1. Corresponde a un [tema válido para SO ES](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
2. Ha seguido las [pautas para escribir una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Me parece que las preguntas de errores "muy leves" podrían o no cumplir con lo arriba indicado. Si la pregunta incluye información sobre lo que el autor ha buscado, lo que ha intentado, incluye un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), etc., no debería borrarse y merece una respuesta aunque la misma sea "muy leve" y la respuesta correcta fuera "sencilla".

He puesto "muy leve" y "sencilla" entre comillas pues ambos términos son adjetivos subjetivos. SO ES no excluye las preguntas que para unos sean así ya que para otros podrían ser de utilidad.

Por otro lado, si el autor de la pregunta publicó una mala pregunta y no está dispuesto a convertirla en una buena pregunta por la razón que sea, lo mejor es que la borre.